# Add current fragment to backstack: Android

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, back-stack

I am adding a fragment in an activity, fragment A. 
Now from this fragment, I go to various other fragments, and whenever I go to those, I replace fragment A.

But there is only one scenario when i want that when i am about to go from fragment A to fragment Z, I add fragment A to the back stack. 
So basically for all the clicks on fragment A, which take the user to other fragments (by replacing fragment A), there is only click where I want that fragment A be put in the back stack, this i want as when i press back from this new fragment Z, I do not want the activity to finish, rather i want fragment A to just come back up.

Now one dirty way of doing this is to do the following:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

    if ( getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(FragmentZ.class.toString()) == null){
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
    else {
        //i would add fragment A over here.
    }
}
```

But I was thinking that if i could add fragment A into the back stack just before i go to fragment Z then i do not have to take care of the above.

Could some please help me with the above?

Answer (score 3):

The only way you can add Fragment A to the back stack is before you commit the transaction which replaces Fragment A with Fragment Z.

You can not add it later on after Fragment Z is already added.

Before calling `commit()` on the transaction which inserts Fragment Z, call `addToBackStack(null)` on the the transaction.

Then you will not have to override `onBackPressed()`.